# accessing the docker container for rabbitmq from ubuntu host

Tags: ubuntu, docker, rabbitmq

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and am trying to Run a Docker image of RabbitMQ (from docker hub). I am following the steps mentioned in link:
[Running RabbitMQ Docker container with Management plugin enabled](https://marketplace.automic.com/details/rabbitmq-official-docker-image)

here is the command that I actually run(in case above link does not work):

```
$ sudo docker run -d -e RABBITMQ_NODENAME=my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 8080:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

and it seems working well as I verified it by running the following command(I see container up and running)`$ sudo docker ps -l`

Also, when I see the log afterwards, that shows me that all the plugins are enabled.
Now, I am trying to access the RabbitMQ Management console of this docker container using firefox on ubuntu host and it never serves any page.
I am using following URL in firefox:

[http://172.17.0.2:15672](http://172.17.0.4:17:15672) 
where 172.17.0.2 is IP address of container I found using `$ sudo docker inspect containerid`.

Any help is highly appreciated...

Comment: Try on the port 8080

Comment: I tried that too @user2915097,but in vain. Finally, re-installing the docker itself worked... `$ sudo apt-get remove docker.io` followed by `$ sudo apt-get install docker.io` ... not sure if docker daemon itself had some issues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your docker run command verbatim and it works just fine.

`docker ps -l` will list the latest container created, regardless if it is running or stopped, check the status column if the container is actually running, I'm guessing it's not.

If it is actually up and running you probably messed up reading the correct ip from `docker inspect`. As your run command includes a port mapping `-p 8080:15672` you should be able to also access the management console via port 8080 on your host interfaces, i.e. via http://localhost:8080.

Comment: thanks... I did see the docker ps -l showing status as "up since...". The thing that worked for me was just un-installing the docker.io and re-installing that. I am guessing somehow docker daemon service had some issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but on centOS 8. I fixed it by ensuring the server's firewall allows incoming connections on port 15672. These are the commands I executed:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=15672/tcp --permanent

sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```